# Strange rendering artifacts when adding overviews to my geotiff (gdaladdo)

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tilemill, gdaladdo

I have a geotiff that I want to render using Tilemill. It's a quite large area, so I need to create overviews for it. Otherwise the rendering performance is just very bad. (Maybe somebody has other ideas on how to improve rendering performance?)

Here are some stats about my geotiff:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: oek_colored_backup.tif
Size is 712800, 352640
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"]]
Origin = (1038800.000000000349246,6279600.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.250000000000000,-1.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1038800.000, 6279600.000) (  9d19'54.12"E, 49d 1'40.51"N)
Lower Left  ( 1038800.000, 5838800.000) (  9d19'54.12"E, 46d21'48.76"N)
Upper Right ( 1929800.000, 6279600.000) ( 17d20' 8.48"E, 49d 1'40.51"N)
Lower Right ( 1929800.000, 5838800.000) ( 17d20' 8.48"E, 46d21'48.76"N)
Center      ( 1484300.000, 6059200.000) ( 13d20' 1.30"E, 47d42'45.92"N)
Band 1 Block=712800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=712800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=712800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

So now when I use the tiff without overviews, everything renders fine, but... it would take about 60 days to export the region that I want to export. Which is bad...
If I render the same area with a tif that contains overviews, it takes about one day, which is ok. The only problem is that as soon as my tif has overviews in it, it starts to make strange edges on the tiles. It seems like data is somehow shifted or translated or something. I attached an image to better see it. I marked the most obvious regions.

I created the overviews using `gdaladdo -r average --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW input.tif 4 8 16 32`. I also tried bilinear resampling, but same effect. So I stopped trying others...

Would be very glad for a pointer in the right direction.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here's `gdalinfo` after enabling tiling:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: oek_colored_tiled_with_overviews_inside.tif
Size is 712800, 352640
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (1038800.000000000349246,6279600.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.250000000000000,-1.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1038800.000, 6279600.000) (  9d19'54.12"E, 49d 1'40.51"N)
Lower Left  ( 1038800.000, 5838800.000) (  9d19'54.12"E, 46d21'48.76"N)
Upper Right ( 1929800.000, 6279600.000) ( 17d20' 8.48"E, 49d 1'40.51"N)
Lower Right ( 1929800.000, 5838800.000) ( 17d20' 8.48"E, 46d21'48.76"N)
Center      ( 1484300.000, 6059200.000) ( 13d20' 1.30"E, 47d42'45.92"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 178200x88160, 89100x44080, 44550x22040, 22275x11020, 11138x5510, 5569x2755
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 178200x88160, 89100x44080, 44550x22040, 22275x11020, 11138x5510, 5569x2755
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 178200x88160, 89100x44080, 44550x22040, 22275x11020, 11138x5510, 5569x2755
```

Comment: Do you see the same artifacts if you open the image that has overviews with QGIS? A hint for testing overviews: If you create external overviews by using `-ro` it is easier to compare the results and remove the overviews totally by renaming and deleting the .ovr file. Is your original GeoTIFF tiled? If it is not that would explain a great deal of slow rendering.

Comment: The original geotiff is one large geotiff. It was not colorized, so I used gdal to colorize it (as tilemill could not properly resample AND color it).
Unfortunately the geotiff lives on a headless server and is quite large (about 13GB). So not that easy to get it on my machine for inspection with QGIS.

Would gdal2tiles be a tool to tile it? And then make a vrt geotiff? Would that improve rendering?

I'll update my answer with the complete output of gdalinfo.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It might be enough to re-write your TIFF into a new tiled TIFF and you must do that in any case. Now the TIFF is striped row-by-row  `Block=712800x1`. For reading 256x256 pixels at original scale the rendering software must read 256 rows with 712800 pixels on each row. You see that it's quite an overhead.

Comment: `gdal_translate -co tiled=yes -co bigtiff=yes -co compress=lzw untiled.tif tiled.tif` then create the overviews as a separate file with the `-ro` flag`gdaladdo -ro  -r average --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW tiled.tif 4 8 16 32`

Comment: May I ask one more question. Rendering is now fast when zoomed in, but it seems that the external overviews are not used in Tilemill? At least they render extremely slow...
But according to gdalinfo, those overviews should be there now...

Comment: When now adding the overviews INTO the file (so without the `-ro`), rendering when zoomed out is now very fast again, but there is the offset (as shown in the image) again... it's a bit different than in the image... but still basically the same.
I updated my answer with gdalinfo of the new file that also includes the overviews internally